# Add Contact with custom label programmatically from an iOS App To device Address Book which is synched with Outlook Account

Tags: ios, outlook

[image][image]I want to add contact information with custom labels (Eg: cell,private etc) from my iOS app to device local address book. I did it using ABAddressBookRef.

After I synced my contacts with outlook account, whenever I add contact from App to address book, its not allowing me to add contacts with custom label in iPhone (both programmatically and manually).

When I added a contact, the custom label **Cell** was replaced by default label **home** for phone number.

And almost all of my app users have outlook account. Can anyone suggest me a solution for this.Is there any way to programatically identify device have default acount set to outlook?

Comment: You may consider using EWS. See [EWS Managed API, EWS, and web services in Exchange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877012(v=exchg.150).aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to add custom label for any phone number-

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL; 
ABAddressBookRef iPhoneAddressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
ABRecordRef newPerson = ABPersonCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonFirstNameProperty, @"Gill", &error);

const CFStringRef customLabel = CFSTR( "Enter any label here" );

ABMutableMultiValueRef customPhone = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABMultiStringPropertyType);
ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(customPhone, @"1-555-555-555", customLabel, NULL); 
ABRecordSetValue(newPerson, kABPersonPhoneProperty, customPhone,nil);
CFRelease(customPhone);

ABAddressBookAddRecord(iPhoneAddressBook, newPerson, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(iPhoneAddressBook, &error);

if (error != NULL)
{   
    NSLog(@"Error!");   
}
```

Comment: I used the same code for creating custom labels. Are you sure that this code works perfectly, if your contacts is synced with outlook account. Why I am asking this is, When I try to create the contact manually from address book also, I was not able to see the Add Custom Label option.  https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2153421

Comment: I had set the default account (under Mail, Contacts, Calendars in Seetings) to my Exchange account.

Comment: Yes you can add custom label to any phone numbers when you are adding phone number manually in address book. Tap on the label itself  not the number or anything else to get the list and custom label.

Comment: I tapped on the label only. But Add custom label option is not visible for me. Most important thing is this scenario only happens after device contact default account is set to outlook. Please see attached screen shots. –